# What is tag 'numeric-format' as distinct from 'number-formatting'? Aren't these essentially the same?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There is a tag [number-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/number-formatting) and also a tag [numeric-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric-format) with no definition, 21 questions, about half of those C#/.NET; unclear how and why the latter was created. Aren't these essentially the same thing?

- [number-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/number-formatting) refers to the **act of converting** one of various types of number into a string representation ('numeric format')
- [numeric-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numeric-format) refers to that **actual (choice of) string representation for a number**, e.g. `1.23456e+78` or `1'234.56` are two different formats
- but fundamentally aren't these interchangeable and co-occurring?

(I stumbled across this when retagging [Force R not to use exponential notation (e.g. e+10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10). 'exponential notation' is really a near-alias to 'scientific notation', but that's another tag story...)

Comment: They are excellent contextual tags, they very clearly describe intent.  But *everybody* knows something about numeric formatting and nobody has enough answers to rank as an expert.  So no need to fix anything.  You are probably going to propose a synonym anyway, there isn't anybody that can vote for it.  Just don't worry about it.

Comment: @HansPassant If we can't create a synonym, we should probably retag all the [tag:numeric-format] questions to [tag:number-formatting], effectively burning [tag:numeric-format]. That would prevent it from getting suggested to users when tagging, at least. [tag:numeric-format] is quite small, so that should be doable.